# is it faster to reference a textbox's text property for a test or assign a string to the property then test?

Tags: c#, performance

I've been wondering which is faster (or if it even makes a difference), referencing a textbox's Text property or a string assigned to that value?
Ref textbox.Text

```
if(textbox1.Text == "A")
{ //do a million iterations
}
```

Or

```
string aString = textbox1.Text;
if(aString == "A")
{ //do a million iterations
}
```

Comment: Well it depends on what's in the block. Are you going to reference the `textbox1.Text` property inside?

Comment: @Dani, are you going to use the text in the if block?

Comment: There is no reasonable answer here.  I would actually argue that these get simplified at compile time, and end up being executed exactly the same.  (Assuming aString, is not referenced anywhere else).

Comment: yea, lets say I reference textbox1.Text in the 1st example and aString in the second , adding and removing a char on each iteration if `x% == 0` in a for loop respectively

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Knuth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made just a quick analyze using stop watch: 10.000.000 iterations.

In first case it returns to me:   00:00:21.56

In second case it returns to me:  00:00:42.62

In second case you have Get accessor + new pointer to string every iteration, so its slower.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

I put **all** code of any case inside the iteration. Seems that is the  quetion.

Comment: was mine curiosity too, seemed strange to me that everyone says that second one is faster.

Comment: yea, I agree, kinda surprised about the result myself though

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will make any difference if compiler optimisation is on, but you could test this. Simply repeat the code a couple of million times with a StopWatch class to measure the timing of the total operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second option is faster. Reading the property is executing a function which reads the value of the textbox. There is a chance it gets optimized away, on the other hand there may be also a chance the value changes while the loop is executing so it needs to check it every time the property is read.